# Data Relationship patterns

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

```
Tables:
-Incidents
--references locations thru location_id
-Locations
--references areas thru area_id
-Areas
```

Each area, has locations, and incidents can occur at any location.

How can I setup the relationship such that I can have eloquent grab, all incidents in a area, or location?

Would I have to reference the area_id in the incidents table also?

Comment: It's better not to references area_id in incident model : if the area of a location change, the incident would be linked to the wrong area.

Comment: You may want to look at the relationship type [hasManyThrough](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#has-many-through) which will be able to join Incidents to Areas while maintaining the intermediate relationship with Locations. That way you should be able to use `$area->incidents` to simply get a list of incidents in a given area.

Comment: Thanks @alexrussell, I see how it applies to this situation now

Comment: Obviously the inverse of that relationship isn't as simple, but it's almost as simple: just do `$incident->location->area` to get the area an incident is in.

Comment: Dude, you beat me to it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do nested relationship queries as well.

Eg:

```
Incidents::with(array('location', function($q) use ($areaId) {
    return $q->where('area_id', $areaId);
}))->get();
```

Look at 'eager loading constraints' under http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Answer (score 2):

The area_id should not be referenced in the incidents table since indirectly it is already there through location_id.

When designing relational database table structures always apply **[normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)** and bring your schemata to the 3rd normal form if possible.

What exactly is the problem? You already described the relationships between your tables. If there's anything specific about the concrete implementation, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I think i was on the right direction, @hannesvdvreken cleared up how i should approach it from the eloquent orm side of things.